# Help understanding the axiom of regularity

Tags: set-theory

If 0={}, 1={0}, 2={0,1} and so forth, the axiom of regularity holds for every natural number, since for each natural number n, there is an element x in n which is disjoint from n.
However, if we define 0={1}, 1={2}, 2={3} and so on (infinite descending sequence), regularity does no hold, given that there is not a single element of the set S = { all n : n is a natural number }  which is disjoint of S. Is that correct?

Comment: How can you define $0=\{1\}$ if you haven't defined $1$ yet?

Comment: You'd have to justify why your $0 = \{1\}$ is a set, for example. Recursive definitions *need* a base case.

Comment: Is that not the canonical definition of an infinite descending sequence (S = { for all x in IN : f(x+1) is in f(x)} )? If not, could you give me a concrete example of such sequence using natural numbers only?

Comment: @TylerD007 In order for you to use the naturals in a descending sequence, they all need to be well-defined as sets beforehand. So no, it is not possible.

Comment: The idea behind the axiom is to prevent sets from containing copies of themselves at any level.

Comment: If no infinite descending sequence of natural numbers can be constructed, applying the axiom of regularity or not, why does the wikipedia article about the axiom of regularity uses this exact same example to illustrate it?

Comment: The wikipedia article uses this example to show that it is absurd (that is, that a contradiction follows if you asume that)

Comment: I don’t see where the exact same example is used on the Wikipedia page. There are two different things under the heading of “No infinite descending...” that could be mistaken for this but I’m not sure which one you’re mistaking it for (or if it’s another passage ive missed).

Comment: I believe he is referring to the section 'Elementary implications on regularity', and its 'No infinite descending sequence of sets exist'

Comment: @Shiranai Yes, as I said, both the first and third paragraph there are different ideas that OP could be mistaking for what they wrote down, but I’m not sure which one.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct (strictly speaking you are not defining correctly, but your general idea is right). There are models in which Regularity does not hold. Regularity is an Axiom, meaning we assume it is true, however there is no proof of that. So there is plenty of examples where regularity does not hold (e.g. just consider $x=\{x\}$ and regularity does not hold).

Mathematicians assume Regularity because such examples are 'not nice'. That is to say they are unexpected and unwanted. Regularity is not needed for some important basic theorems (induction, calculus, arithmetic) but it imposes 'nicer' sets, those which follow common mathematical intuition. Per @Hanul s comment, it is necessary for some other important theorems though.

Comment: Agree with your second paragraph. But neither what you nor the op wrote down are definitions of sets in the usual sense. Rather they are hypothetical scenarios that are consistent in the absence of regularity. (In other words, what I’m objecting to is both your uses of the verb “define” when you are doing no such thing.)

Comment: You are defining a property (being a Quine atom) and it is consistent in ZF$^-$ that sets with this property exist. I might write your usage off as minor sloppiness if you weren’t agreeing with the OP’s much more flagrant non-definition definition.

Comment: Indeed, strictly speaking neither of us is defining, more correctly we are 'expressing' I guess. I've changed my answer accordingly. However, I think that that is a really minor problem compared to his confusion about how axioms work.

Comment: You need to clarify what 'most important theorems' are. Usual mathematical results (like propositions on analysis and geometry) would not need the axiom of regularity, but some deeper set theory heavily relies on the axiom of regularity. As a side note, a regularity-free proof of "the existence of a basis on any vector spaces implies AC" is not known.

Comment: My bad, I should have not said that.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: ZF$^-$ usually denotes ZF without Power Set, whereas ZF$_0$ denotes ZF without regularity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

As people have noted in the comments your definition doesn’t make a lot of sense (even if sets don’t need to be well founded, recursive definitions need to be). And more generally, you will never succeed at defining an infinite descending membership sequence in ZF minus regularity, because it is consistent that no such sequence exists.

Now, it is also consistent with ZF minus regularity that there is a countable sequence of distinct sets $x_n$ such that $x_n =\{x_{n+1}\}$ for all $n$. But even still, you can’t just define the natural numbers as $n=x_n$ unless you actually add antifoundation axioms to the theory that will allow you not only to prove the existence of such a sequence but to define a canonical one.

But this whole thing about the natural numbers feels like a non sequitur. It seems like the content of your question is really whether the existence of an infinite sequence such that $x_n=\{x_{n+1}\}$  implies that regularity fails. The answer to that is yes: in ZF minus regularity we can define the set $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ from 
the sequence, and this set violates regularity. This follows more generally from any infinite descending sequence where $x_{n+1}\in x_n.$ If we also assume choice in the base theory (or even just dependent choice) then the implication goes the other way and the failure of the axiom of regularity implies the existence of an infinite descending sequence. (Thanks to Hanul Jeon in the comments for pointing out that the converse requires choice.)

Comment: Is there a choice-free proof of the axiom of regularity from the non-existence of $\in$-decreasing sequence?

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes. If such a sequence exists then $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ would violate regularity. That doesn't use choice.

Comment: I got it, but how about its converse? The only proof I can imagine uses dependent choice.

Comment: @HanulJeon Ahh, I don't know how I didn't catch on immediately that you meant the converse. Yeah, I suspect you're right.

Comment: @HanulJeon (And I don't know I only caught on that you *said* the converse when I read your comment again 20 minutes later. Guess it reads funny to me in the contrapositive.)

Comment: Well, this is possible. I often make a ridiculous error and didn't fix it until someone points it out.